Angular Firestore Session Persistence and Authorization
I have guards in my Angular app protecting routes from unauthenticated access and also access from users without administrator privileges. The privileges are retrieved from my Firestore database. I've been able to protect routes, but I cannot do it while maintaining the session through refreshes, and vice versa. The way I have stored session information is using the user's Firebase Auth UID as a token by storing it in the browser local storage upon login and storing and retrieving the session information from Firestore with it. I've put the code for my guard protecting routes from nonadministrator access as well as the service code that should be providing this guard and the guard protecting routes from unauthenticated access.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminGuard {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return combineLatest([
      this.authService.getLoggedIn(),
      this.authService.getAdmin()
    ]).pipe(
      map(([isLoggedIn, isAdmin]) => {
        if (isLoggedIn == false || isAdmin == false) {
          this.router.navigate(['']);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    );
  }
}


export class AuthService {
  private isLoggedInSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private isAdminSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private ID = localStorage.getItem("UID");
  private firestore = firebase.firestore();

  constructor() {
    if (this.ID) {
      this.getData();
    }
  }

  async getData() {
    if(this.ID){
    await this.firestore.collection("session").doc(this.ID).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const data = querySnapshot.data();
      if (data) {
        this.isLoggedInSubject.next(data['isLoggedIn']);
        this.isAdminSubject.next(data['isAdmin']);
      }
    });
    }
  }

  getLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoggedInSubject.asObservable();
  }

  getAdmin(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isAdminSubject.asObservable();
  }


  setLoggedIn(status: boolean): void {
    this.ID = localStorage.getItem("UID")
    if (this.ID) {
      this.firestore.collection("session").doc(this.ID).set({
        'isLoggedIn': status
      }, { merge: true })
    }
    this.isLoggedInSubject.next(status);
  }

  setAdmin(isAdmin: boolean): void {
    this.ID = localStorage.getItem("UID")
    if (this.ID) {
      this.firestore.collection("session").doc(this.ID).set({
        'isAdmin': isAdmin
      }, { merge: true })
    }
    this.isAdminSubject.next(isAdmin);
  }


I've tried putting getData() before each request for either of the variable booleans but it didn't work to maintain the session. I think the issue is with the timing of the operations but I can't figure it out.
